# how to make sure if user enter a number?

Tags: java, string, integer, joptionpane

i want to make sure data entered by users is not a String and if it's show a message!

```
String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number : ",null);
```

here is more information for what i'm doing

```
                String guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Guess Number : ",null);
                if((Integer.parseInt(guess) < 1))
                {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter a number Greater than 0!");
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you won 1,000 $", "winner!"
                            , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
```

Comment: you want to check is number,char  or boolean ?

Comment: no,i want just check if is entered data type is not an integer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a String is a numeric type in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by parsing the value entered by the user and if it's not a valid number then show the error dialog using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`. E.g.

```
String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number : ",null);
boolean isValidNumber = false;
try {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(number));
    isValidNumber  = true;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(), "Invalid number", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(number)); //its never gonna be true,i know should use scanner but i want make my game by JOptionPane(For Selection Options)

Comment: @MR1 you need to use a boolean variable obviously.

Comment: i know but it's different.tnx

Answer (score 2):

If you expect an integer, this should do it

```
boolean isInteger = false;
try {
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(number);
    isInteger = true;
} catch (NumberFormatException) {
    // it's not a integer, handle the exception
}
```

Comment: nop,i have a random generator not scanner, and i want check user guess,tnx for your answer

Comment: This code checks if some string (`number` variable) can be parsed to Integer or not, it doesn't have anything to do with scanner. Weather you get that `number` from scanner, random generator, web service or something else is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to verify that the value entered is a number BEFORE closing the option pane.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) for an approach that will allow you to validate the text entered before closing the dialog.